# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest can't get variable out of closure

Tags: ios, post, asynchronous, swift, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to get a simple text response from a PHP page using POST. I have the following code:

```
func post(url: String, info: String) -> String {
    var URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    var output = "Nothing Returned";
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    var bodyData = info;
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){

        response, data, error in

        output = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))!


    }

    return output
}
```

While this code does not throw any errors, when I make a call to it like this:

```
println(post(url, info: data))
```

It only prints: "Nothing Returned" even though if I were to change the line:

```
output = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))!
```

to this:

```
println((NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)))
```

it does print out the proper response. Am I doing something wrong with my variables here?

Comment: sendAsynchronousRequest is an asynchronous request so you wont get the value of output right after the block. You need to implement a callback mechanism in order to handle it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is calling asynchronous function that is using a completion handler block/closure. So, you need to employ the completion handler pattern in your own code. This consists of changing the method return type to `Void` and adding a new `completionHandler` closure that will be called when the asynchronous call is done:

```
func post(url: String, info: String, completionHandler: (NSString?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let URL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let bodyData = info
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { response, data, error in
        guard data != nil else {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            return
        }

        completionHandler(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding), nil)
    }
}
```

Or, since `NSURLConnection` is now formally deprecated, it might be better to use `NSURLSession`:

```
func post(url: String, info: String, completionHandler: (NSString?, NSError?) -> ()) -> NSURLSessionTask {
    let URL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let bodyData = info
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            guard data != nil else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }

            completionHandler(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding), nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    return task
}
```

And you call it like so:

```
post(url, info: info) { responseString, error in
    guard responseString != nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    // use responseString here
}

// but don't try to use response string here ... the above closure will be called
// asynchronously (i.e. later)
```

Note, to keep this simple, I've employed the trailing closure syntax (see *Trailing Closure* section of [The Swift Programming Language: Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_151)), but hopefully it illustrates the idea: You cannot immediately return the result of an asynchronous method, so provide a completion handler closure that will be called when the asynchronous method is done.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I believe you've answered my question, however do you think I should use sendAsynchronousRequest? I'm using this for a login script, so maybe sendSynchronousRequest is better?

Comment: You almost never want to use `sendSynchronousRequest` (and the only place you would use it is from background thread, where it's effectively asynchronously with respect to the main thread, anyway). Use `sendAsynchronousRequest`, like above, and put any code contingent upon the successful login _inside_ the completion handler of the `post` call. This is the heart of all network programming: do it asynchronously and put dependent code in the completion handlers.

Comment: Or, as pointed out in the revision to this answer, you should not use `NSURLConnection` at all, anymore, because it's now deprecated. You really should be using `NSURLSession`, which doesn't even offer a synchronous rendition (which is a good design decision, IMHO).