# Asynchronous Request not properly updating variables

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm attempting to grab source from a page online to parse it and put the information into an array. The request goes through fine, and html has the source as a string as I would like. The problem is, after this function, even though html and sbcc are global, the values I've added disappear. Even the "Test" in the parse function does not appear. I think it has something to do with the request being asynchronous? I've searched, but it's only brought me to ideas I didn't quite understand, or doesn't really cover my specific question. My code snippets are below, if anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com");
var html = String()
var sbcc = courselisting();

func getSource(url: NSURL){
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (response, data, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            println("whoops, something went wrong")

            let alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: "Something went wrong",       delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Reload")

            alert.show()

        } else {
            //println(self.html)
            self.html = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            self.parse()

        }
    }

}

func parse() {
    sbcc.subjects.append("Test")
    sbcc.subjects.append(html.substringToIndex(advance(html.startIndex, 2)))
    println(self.html)
}
```

EDIT: following zisoft's advice i removed the passing of the html string into `parse()` in my above code, however my global string html still does not have the appended values. for more info here is the main portion of `viewDidLoad`

```
getSource(url!);

println(self.html)
```

it is printing blank in the `viewDidLoad` but the println inside of parse prints out the proper HTML.

Comment: I feel like it must have something to do with the `in` on the Asynchronous Request. I just don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've Solved it! using Rob's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569724/nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequest-cant-get-variable-out-of-closure?rq=1). basically I need to do all asynchronous activity WITHIN the asynch call and just have everything refresh when complete.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are passed by value to functions. So you are appending to a copy of `html`.
Since you declared `html` in a global scope there is no need to pass it to the function:

```
{
   ...
   self.parse()
}

func parse() {
    sbcc.subjects.append("Test")
    sbcc.subjects.append(html.substringToIndex(advance(html.startIndex, 2)))
    println(self.html)
}
```

Comment: thank you! I'll have to look up the swift syntax for pass by reference. I'll try that fix and report back. I seem to remember prior to creating a separate function `parse()` it still wasn't working properly.