# Start animating UIActivityIndicator when image downloads throug contentsOfURL synchronous

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to show `UIActivityIndicator` when images start downloading, and it animate until all images are downloads.
But `UIActivityIndicator` not animate, it animate when all images are downloads. I've found that `contentsOfURL` is synchronous method and blocks the main thread. I want to use `contentsOfURL` for downloading images. Anyone have any idea how i can animate `UIActivityIndicator` when images start downloading?
Thanks

```
var indeX = 0  
var imageArrayNsData : [NSData] = []
var posts = NSMutableArray()

myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
self.view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false

for _ in posts.valueForKey("enclosure") as! [NSString]{
    let picURL = self.posts.objectAtIndex(indeX).valueForKey("enclosure") as! String
    let url = NSURL(string: picURL)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let IMG = UIImage(data: data!)
    let dtA : NSData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(IMG!)!)
    print("download")
    imageArrayNsData.append(dtA)
    indeX++
    print(indeX)
}                   
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

Comment: plz post full code

Comment: Don't download synchronously on the main thread.  It's never the right thing.  Ever.

Comment: What is simple method to download `Asynchronously` image from `URL` wiithout using `Dispatch`and `AlamofireImage` library? Thanks

Comment: @ZAFAR007 Use NSURLSession. There's many [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343547/2227743) on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it Asynchronously, you will have to use `dispatch`. Infact, `AlamofireImage` uses dispatch to handle it as well.

In my opinion, you could have your code in a dispatch for queue user initial and update the main queue when completed for the `myActivityIndicator` and `self.view.userInteractionEnabled`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue), 0)) { 
  //your download code here

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
   }  
}
```

Comment: `Value of type 'qos_class_t' has no member 'value'`

Comment: sorry, in swift 2 is changed to `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can use it on ios 7.0 because it is only available in ios 8. Thanks

Comment: Can you please send me previous code that you wrote before edit?

Comment: Hey, the previous code before edit is just without the `.rawValue`. So is just `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value`

Comment: I want to run it on minimum ios 7.0 or ios 7.1. Have you any idea how i can run it  because i think this is only available for ios8??