# Void Inside of Return function

Tags: ios, swift, function, return, void

I am trying to create a custom class for clicking pictures. Inside of it, I would like to create a `clickPicture` function that returns a `UIImage`. However, the `captureStillImageAsynchronously` is a `void`. How can I return the image I receive from that? Thanks.

```
func clickPicture() -> UIImage? {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

        videoConnection.videoOrientation = .portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

            if sampleBuffer != nil {

                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData!)
                let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)

                let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1, orientation: .right)

                return image //Unexpected non-void return value in void function

            }
            return nil //Unexpected non-void return value in void

        })

    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Side note: Please avoid the puramid of doom. Video connection and sampleBuffercan both be checked with a `guard let`, rather than an `if let`

Comment: @AMomchilov what is the difference? I generally use `if let`.

Comment: Essentially the same problem as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569724/nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequest-cant-get-variable-out-of-closure.

Comment: @penatheboss `guard` binds a variable for the rest of the scope. For example, you can replace `if sampleBuffer != nil { /* code */ } return nil` with `guard let sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer else { return nil } /* code */` The `/* code */ part wouldn't be nested in the if block

Comment: @penatheboss It's especially useful in cases where you may have (for example) 10 preconditions to check. Rather than nesting an `if` in an `if` ... 10 times, you can just put 10 consecutive `guard`s.

Comment: Would it make the same difference if I put `if sampleBuffer == nil { return nil } /* code */? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the unchallenged #2 Swift question after *unexpected nil found while unwrapping an optional*.

The method describes pretty well what is does :

> capture still image **asynchronously**.

You cannot return anything from a method which contains an asynchronous task.
You need a completion block:

```
func clickPicture(completion:(UIImage?) -> Void) {

    guard let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)  else { completion(nil) }

    videoConnection.videoOrientation = .portrait
    stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

        guard let buffer = sampleBuffer else { completion(nil) }

        let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
        let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData!)
        let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)

        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1, orientation: .right)

        completion(image) 

    })
}
```

and call it this way:

```
clickPicture { image in 
   if unwrappedImage = image {
     // do something with unwrappedImage
   } 
}
```