# FMDatabaseQueue How To Return A Value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

Please refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765874/fmdatabasequeue-how-to-return-a-value) of **FMDatabaseQueue How To Return A Value**. It said the function just return the value at the end of the function. But my code in swift doesn't work this way. Here is my code:

```
class func isSomethingRight()-> Bool {

    var ret : Bool = false

    self.queue.inDatabase({ database in
        let sql = NSString(format: "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE tableId = '1001'")
        if let resultSet = database.executeQuery(sql, withArgumentsInArray:nil) {                

            if resultSet.next() {
                ret = true
            }
        }
    })        
    return ret
}
```

In my code, the **return ret** return first, then the **ret = true** inside block (closure) called later. What could be wrong in my code? (Actually the exactly same code works in my another project in Swift).

Comment: It all looks right. You're sure that your block is being called later and it's not just returning false correctly? There's a good chance it would cause a crash trying to set `ret` after the method has ended.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that my block was called later after the function returned.